# MYSQL batch insertion failed due to exception

Tags: java, mysql

I a working with java and MYSQL. I want to insert 1000 elements into MYSQL database from java. I created a stored procedure with batch insertion .The problem is that if the insertion of first element or any other element failed due to some SQL exception, the  execution will be stop. I want to insert other elements even if some insertion failed due to SQL exception. How is it possible?

```
public void insertXml(ArrayList<String> xmlCollection) throws SQLException {
Connection connection = null;
CallableStatement statement = null;
try {
    connection = DbConnector.getConnection();
    Application.getAppInstance().monitorCountProcedure("insertXmlToDB");
    statement = connection.prepareCall("{call insertXmlToDB(?)}");
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    
    for (String xmlString : xmlCollection) {
        //System.out.println("xmlstring="+xmlString);
        statement.setString(1, xmlString);
        statement.addBatch();
    }
    statement.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
    System.out.println("insertXmlToDB stored procedure called successfully!" + statement);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println("insertXmlToDB stored procedure error : " + ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (statement != null) {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // log.error("Could not close statement" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Basically show us the Stored Proceedure if you want help

Comment: In MySQL you can use `INSERT IGNORE` in place of just `INSERT` to prevent it from throwing errors when your `INSERT` operations fail due to constraint violations (duplicate primary or unique keys). You can also use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` as a way to handle new data for existing rows. If you [edit]ed your question to show us your stored procedure and tell us what exception you got we'd be able to give more specific advice. Or, if this one is closed please ask another.

Comment: @O.Jones In my table I have a column named callId. Its data type is varchar(40). Sometime stored procedure receive callId with more than 40 characters. That time SQL return an exception and stop the execution.